# How do I download Bloomberg data into Python?

Tags: python-3.x, bloomberg

I have just downloaded the latest Anaconda python 3.6.3.

Now I want too download data from Bloomberg using their api 'import blpapi' but Bloomberg only supports python up to 3.4.4.

- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
  last)  in ()
  ----> 1 import blpapi

  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blpapi'

How can I download their data into Spider or Jupiter notebook. Is there another earlier version of python that I have to download? and if so where?

Many thanks in advance. James

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manage different conda [versions](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#viewing-a-list-of-available-python-versions) of python with environments:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

Then,

1. Activate the new environment.
2. Verify the new environment is your current environment
3. To verify that the current environment uses the new Python version, in your terminal window or an Anaconda Prompt, run:     python --version

All the versions of Bloomberg API are available [here](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/), from 2.6 to 3.4.

Note you need a Bloomberg account to access data via Bloomberg.